# Installing FiIebot on Rasberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Apparently I asked this in the wrong place before...

I want to install Filebot on my RPi (It's an old 1B, I have a 3B+ coming in a few days)

```
sudo apt-get install filebot
```

...does not work

It turns out I have never installed anything via CLI that wasn't able to be done via apt-get and I have no idea what to do!

https://www.filebot.net/#download >> Debian Stretch / Raspberry Pi package: FileBot_4.8.5_universal-jdk8.deb

I read something about using pip (already installed with Raspian), but I can't seem to find any instructions for how to do this?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work". Are there errors? Did you follow the directions about adding the repository (assuming it is built for Pi) https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6028

Comment: If you are downloading the .deb from that link, you can just do `sudo dpkg -i <name_of_file>.deb`

Comment: Eventually I figured it out, I had to add the Filebot APT repository first.  Downloaded Filebot successfully, now just struggling with the license.  It tells me I have activated successfully, but then fails with an unregistered message.